# How to calculate distance matrix from fasta?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, fasta

I’d like to perform the following, but I am having difficulty.

I want to convert amino acid sequences in multifasta files into matrices (or vectors) with Euclidean distance and Pearson correlation coefficient.

If you know a solution, please let me know. Thanking you in advance.

#### File1

```
>BDP27474.1 |surface glycoprotein [Severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2]
MFVFLVLLPL
>BDP27485.1 |surface glycoprotein [Severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2]
MFVFLVLLPL
```

#### File2

```
>BDD77411.1 |surface glycoprotein [Severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2]
MFVFLVLLPL
>BDD77515.1 |surface glycoprotein [Severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2]
MFVFFVLLPL
```

#### Code

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ape)
library(Biostrings)

naseq1 <- readAAStringSet("File1.fasta")
naseq2 <- readAAStringSet("File2.fasta")

dist.aa(naseq1)
dist.aa(naseq2)

##Error in numeric(n * (n - 1)/2) : invalid 'length' argument
```

#### Add info.

iOS 10.15, Rstudio cloud

Comment: It's a _flu_ bug!

Answer (score 0):

If the sequences are already aligned, you can use `seqinr::dist.alignment`:

```
library(seqinr)
dist=dist.alignment(read.alignment("input.fa","fasta"))
100*(1-dist^2) # convert to identity percent
```

If the sequences are not aligned, you can first run `clustalw input.fa -output=fasta` in a shell. You can also run ClustalW within R with the `msa` package (which can be installed with `BiocManager::install("msa")`):

```
> library(msa)
> fasta=readAAStringSet("https://pastebin.com/raw/1SbS0CmS") # SARS spike proteins
> aln=msa(fasta)
> dist=seqinr::dist.alignment(msaConvert(aln,"seqinr::alignment"))
> dist
         banal52     sars2    ratg13      zc45     zxc21
sars2  0.1122869
ratg13 0.1485416 0.1511709
zc45   0.4270004 0.4222715 0.4260588
zxc21  0.4337083 0.4290496 0.4327806 0.1133640
sars1  0.4730972 0.4781392 0.4747838 0.4726475 0.4745558
> round(100*(1-dist^2),1) # convert to identity percent
       banal52 sars2 ratg13 zc45 zxc21
sars2     98.7
ratg13    97.8  97.7
zc45      81.8  82.2   81.8
zxc21     81.2  81.6   81.3 98.7
sars1     77.6  77.1   77.5 77.7  77.5
```

`seqinr::dist.alignment` sometimes gives me segfaults when I try to use it with large files, but `bio3d::seqidentity` seems to handle large files better:

```
library(bio3d)
(1-seqidentity(read.fasta("input.fa")))^2
```

You can also use `-outputtree=dist -tree` with ClustalW (where the distance is just the identity fraction subtracted from one without squaring):

```
$ curl https://pastebin.com/raw/1SbS0CmS|tr -d \\r>sarsspike.fa
$ clustalw sarsspike.fa
[...]
$ clustalw -outputtree=dist -tree -infile=sarsspike.aln
$ sed 1d sarsspike.dst|awk 1
banal52     0.000  0.013  0.022  0.182  0.188  0.224 
sars2       0.013  0.000  0.023  0.178  0.184  0.229 
ratg13      0.022  0.023  0.000  0.182  0.187  0.225 
zc45        0.182  0.178  0.182  0.000  0.013  0.223 
zxc21       0.188  0.184  0.187  0.013  0.000  0.225 
sars1       0.224  0.229  0.225  0.223  0.225  0.000
```

If the sequences are already aligned, you can just use `clustalw -outputtree=dist -tree -infile=input.fa`.